# Unknown Database when trying to connect to an AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database, amazon-rds

I created a MySQL RDS instance, however, when I try to connect without writing the database name, it connects but does not allow me to create any tables. When I do write the name, the connection fails and I don't know why.

**Error**

[image: Error screen shot]
[image: Working screen shot]

I have my endpoint, user, password and the name of the DB, which is `prueba` (test in spanish)

**AWS Console**

[image: AWS Console]

As you can see, the name of the instance is "prueba". And when it asked me to enter the name of the DB in he console, I also worte "prueba"

Comment: Hi Eduardo, if the below answer helped resolve your problem please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way to say *thanks* to people who spent their free time answering your question. Thanks!

Comment: @MLu Tnak you for the answer and Im sorry. I didnt knew I had the level to do that im new to sf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create you create your RDS instance, there is an “Additional configuration” section, in which you can specify the database name, and it warns you that if no name is provided, no database will be created by default.

[image]

But as others have pointed out, you can connect with your tool of choice without a database name, perform a `CREATE DATABASE xxx;` where `xxx` is the name of the database, and then use can use that database going forward.

Comment: This fixed my problem, if you create an RDS DB instance with "Easy create" you skip over this step so make sure to use "Standard create"

Answer (score 8):

The name that you circled in the second screenshot is not a *mysql database* name, it's merely an identifier how your *database instance* is known as in AWS, i.e. *endpoint name*. These may be different!

Since logging in without specifying the *MySQL database name* works it means your connectivity and credentials are correct. You can't create tables because you *didn't select a database* where to create these tables.

---

**So why can't you connect with a database name specified?**

I suspect your *default database name* that was created by AWS when setting up the RDS instance isn't `prueba` but something else. You should be able to figure that you in the RDS Details tab:

[image: Database Details]

Note that my *Endpoint Name* is `prueba` but the *MySQL Database Name* is `something`.

I can login to the RDS and list the databases:

```
~ $ mysql -h prueba.xxxxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com -uroot -p
Enter password: 
Server version: 5.6.40 Source distribution

MySQL [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| innodb             |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| something          |      <<<< Here is my "default" database
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

---

So to wrap it up - you'll have to figure out your actual mysql database name:

- *find out* what was the default database name that you specified when creating the instance **from the RDS Details screen**, or
- *find out* the database name by logging in without a db name specified and then run **`SHOW DATABASES;`**, or
- **create a new one** using `CREATE DATABASE whatever;` or using some dialog in your DB tool.

Once you've got the database name you can then connect to it in your *connect dialog* or with `USE whatever;` and then you can finally **create your tables**.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case db name was null so i left it empty when connecting with MySQL client.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA9mn.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create tables without creating a database first. Login without db name, create a new database and then create tables. That will work.

Comment: the weird is, how aws rds display the info about db configurations: db instance, db name etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue while trying to connect a PHP login to an AWS MySQL Database, I mistook the DB identifier as the database name, the form refused to connect until I removed the Database name.

Answer (score 0):

Our db was created by a previous employee and no name was established on creation. I was connecting to a new service which required a name (most connections don't). As the default name when using postgres db is `postgres` if you don't specify at time of creation, I tried `mysql` and this worked.